# Magento 2 How to remove menu item in admin portal?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, menu

There are some menu items that are unnecessary for us. How can I remove them? Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific so we can help you easier?  Are these chunks core to Magento?  The answer could depend.  They are not categories correct?

Comment: For example, there is "Credit Memos" under Sales -> Operations, but it unnecessary for us. We want to remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using remove tag  you can remove a menu item from admin menu.

Syntax should be **`<remove id="MENU_ITEM_ID" />`**

Suppose I want to **remove Cms page  section from menu**, then I have to rewrite below code **at menu.xml** of my module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
    <remove id="Magento_Cms::cms_page" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

**Magento_Cms::cms_page** is menu id of cms page ,which is define at at [vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml#L10) .

Comment: any chance we can remove via php code through plugin or observer?

Answer (score 0):

If item is category u can check option `Include in Navigation Menu` **No** in product->categories.